# Maven Eclipse Java errors The hierarchy of the type ... is inconsistent

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have read posts that seem similar, but I have not found any that lead to a solution yet.

I am editing in Eclipse Juno on Windows 7.

I have run `maven clean install war:inplace` from a command line in the project directory that contains **two** build errors.  **NOTE: Maven builds `ProjectB` successfully.**

I am pretty sure both error messages are directly related.

**Errors**

1. `The hierarchy of the type SomeClassB is inconsistent` error on `SomeClassB` and
2. `The type javax.servlet.Servlet cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` on `SomeClassC`

The two errors appear on the code below in the class declaration line after the imports:

```
import foo.bar.one.a.base.SomeClassA;
import foo.bar.two.b.property.PropertyX;

public abstract class SomeClassB extends SomeClassC{

    public SomeClassB() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected PropertyX getPropertyX() {
        return SomeClassA.getPropertyX(this.getPropName());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPropName() {
        return SomeClassA.PROPERTY_NAME;
    }

}
```

Some things to note:

1. SomeClassC is defined in another project.  I will call it `ProjectC`
2. The code above is from `ProjectB`.  The pom.xml file for `ProjectB` **does** contain a reference to `ProjectC`. See below code:

**pom.xml**

**Edit: All dependencies added**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.wps</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.jsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.jsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl-messages</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.jsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-portletbridge</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.jsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-ibm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar.one.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo1</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar.one.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo2</artifactId>
        <version>${foovar2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar.one.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>PropertyX</artifactId>
        <version>${property.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar.one.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectC</artifactId>
        <version>${varname.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar.one.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo3</artifactId>
        <version>${foovar3.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar.one.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo4</artifactId>
        <version>${foovar4.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <properties>
        ...
        <varname.version>5.2.85373</varname.version>
        ...
    </properties>
```

I have ensured that `ProjectC` and the class do indeed exist on my filesystem and that the path to it is an entry in the .classpath file for `ProjectB`.

A workaround I have tried is to import `ProjectC` into eclipse and add it to `ProjectB`'s Java Build Path.  I do not want to do this becuase that is a discouraged practice on my team.

How can I solve this problem(s)?

Comment: I included (what I thought were) the relevant parts... Do you need more?

Comment: Do you have servlet-api dependency in your pom?

Comment: try providing below dependency with your respective version first.

Comment: @Kalher I do not have that in my pom.

Comment: I am not going to provide the entire pom because it is enormous and I would have to clean up all the sensitive data.  If this is a deal breaker please let me know.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Since it contributes to making your problem unreproducible, it's kind of a problem. Not a deal breaker, but it means people have to guess. Realise that the goal here isn't to appease the fickle whims of SO users, but to give them all the information they need to solve your issue – it's in your interest to make this as easy as possible.

Comment: I understand lol.  Which is why I am working on posting the code :P.  I was hoping the problem may be solvable without posting the dependencies.

Comment: I have added all dependencies (some sensitive information replaced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you run Maven from the command line.

In a nutshell, Eclipse believes that only itself changes the files under `target/classes/`. If you run Maven from the command line, it will change the same files and Eclipse will be very confused.

You have two options:

1. Use Project -> Clean to build everything again.
2. [Configure Eclipse to use a different output folder](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#How_to_configure_Maven_project_to_use_separate_output_folders_in_Eclipse) for builds than Maven from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However: 1. I have cleaned (numerous times) 2. What are the consequences of changing the output folder?

Answer (score -1):

**Provide this dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This was answer of a problem which was itself a guess out of information provided by you, so of course the problem is something else.